# Returning an observable thinks the expression type is OperatorFunction<R,T>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to return an observable from a simple function like so

```
public saveSurvey =(surveyId: number, surveyResponse: SurveyResponse) : Observable<Response> => {
    return this.http.post(this.config.api.survey + surveyId +'/answers', surveyResponse)
     .map((res: Response) =>  res);

};
```

However my IDE (WebStorm) is reporting that

`Returned expression type OperatorFunction<R,T> is not assignable to type Observable<Response>`

As far as I can see all the examples show this pattern working fine, and Http.get does return an Observable.

Comment: which version of typescript are you using .. this issue was fixed in 2.3.4

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17800

Comment: rxjs@5.5.2 and typescript@2.4.2

Comment: can you try removing the `.map((res: Response) =>  res);` part ? and use only the http post

Comment: That does solve the problem in this case, but I have code that requires some processing of `response`

Comment: you can use map on the component  where you are subscribing to the Observable